# Should I move my PHP site into a CMS like Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I have coded a site that I am proud of in PHP. Everything is working fine. But I was told the site needs to be built around CakePHP.

I am somewhat new to building dynamic websites so am not sure if he's correct or not. Right now, if I want to see the data, I go to PHPMyAdmin. If I want to operate on the code, I just open up the PHP files.

Is there a better way that I don't know about? I am not sure why I should re-code the site in CakePHP. Should I? Please explain.

Also, does CakePHP come with certain design templates like Wordpress?

Comment: CakePHP is not a CMS, so the answer to any cms-like question is "no". Who is "he" in the question?

Comment: Some contractor on upWork.com that said I needed to re-do the site if I wanted the site to support a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

There is nothing wrong in sticking with plain PHP if you are comfortable maintaining the contents in PHPMyAdmin. You can even make the site dynamic using GET parameters (example.com/article?id=123) or using a routing framework that allow nice url's such as (example.com/article/hello-world.html).

Personally, I prefer sticking with plain PHP for personal website projects, instead of becoming dependent on a framework or CMS.

No matter if you choose to stick with plain PHP, a framework or a CMS, you still need to figure ways to:

- Route the user request to what ever resources the page should show to the user.
- Security ("never trust user-submitted data") - frameworks help you get security right, and again - you can also sanitize user requests in plain PHP.
- Database queries shall be made (`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 123`), and SQL injection shall be prevented.
- Etc.

Here are a few PHP App Tutorials to get the juices flowing:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Creating-A-PHP-Application.html
- http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-two
- http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/creating-your-first-php-application-part-1/
- http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/creating-an-app-from-scratch-part-7/

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is a CMS - Content Management System.  It is a prebuilt platform that is already for the web, out of the box.

CakePHP, Symfony, Zend, Laravel, etc.  These are frameworks, they are not out of box solutions and require a great deal of coding effort, knowledge and time.

Which one is better is subjective and a matter of personal taste.  It depends what you want to do, what your experience is more geared towards.  Research the different options, and see whats best for you.

Having said that, some of the most populace sites in the world use WordPress.

Comment: So, since I've already built my site using MVC PHP, I would not need to re-build it in a framework like CakePHP?

Comment: The point of a framework is to accelerate the development cycle and make it easier to accomplish objectives without re-inventing things that have already been done a million times over.

Comment: If your website is currently performing well for you, and does what you need.  Then I would say that you need to ask yourself, is there a benefit, beyond 'someone told me to' by doing it?

Comment: I don't mean to be evasive Jon, but I nor anyone else can answer your question.  I built my websites in Symfony after (like you) I built a few without frameworks.  I felt it would be beneficial to my career and ability to learn how to work with them.  So I've since played with Symfony and Zend both.  For me, there was an obvious benefit.  For you, well that's up to you to decide. :)

Comment: If it's for productivity, there is no need to speed up development which already has been made. ;-) If you like to learn from community projects, doing a project with a major framework is a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems to me that I'm past the point of needing a framework since it's already built. 

It seems that I should code it in Wordpress to take advantage of their security patches in the future. What do you think?

Comment: What you need to do Jon, is download these different platforms, and evaluate for yourself what make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why to use frameworks, CMS - and many why not to use them.

- Frameworks help you to focus on your own ideas by often doing the boilerplate stuff for you. Further, they help to keep your code clean. After all, they should ease the development task. Your site is up and running, so you only have to think about further development and maintenance. If you can handle your code, you're fine.
- CMS help you maintain content without coding or low-level database work, which is a pretty "techy" task. If your site is being maintained by more people, a CMS might be a thing to think about.
- Think about security. Widespread systems often get quick fixes for vulnerabilities which would never have been discovered without those millions of running installations. So your own custom system might be pretty secure, even with plenty of security issues being present.